# QGIS install failing with dpkg errors/

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, linux-mint

QGIS stopped working with this error:

```
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
```

I removed/purged everything for a fresh install but I continue to get the same error, I have tried multiple different sources. I can successfully install QGIS 2.8 but 2.14 and 2.18 do not work.

This is the output of attempting to install it with aptitude.

```
 Setting up qgis-providers (2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-provider-grass:
 qgis-provider-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-provider-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis-provider-grass (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis-provider-grass is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-provider-grass
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up qgis-providers (2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: GEOSDelaunayTriangulation_r
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-provider-grass:
 qgis-provider-grass depends on qgis (= 2.14.20+dfsg-1~xenial0); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-provider-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-grass
 qgis-provider-grass
```

I must've updated some part of my system that is causing gdal? to fail. 
I am on Linux Mint 18.1

Comment: You need to remove and purge unused packages from previous installations before starting a new one. Please incluse in your question which version of GDAL you have installed, from ubuntugis-stable, unstable or whereever, and the source you take QGIS from.

Comment: You might try `sudo apt-cache policy gdal` and `sudo apt-cache policy qgis` to see what you have installed, and what is available for you.